# pcl and openni_launch question

Tags: openni, pcl, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I am trying to get my Kinect working with the pcl tutorial programs on the ros.org/wiki/pcl/Tutorials website. I have everything build and when I go to run the program I use these commands.

Start roscore.
Ros launch the openni using roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch.
Then rosrun my example program with the input as the openni point2:
rosrun my_pcl_tutorial example input:=/camera/depth_registered/points.

To see if it is running correctly I used rxgraph and unfortunately it says the communication with my_pcl_tutorial failed. Where have I gone wrong here?

Cheers,
Martin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39556/pcl-and-openni_launch-question/) by [MartinW](https://answers.ros.org/users/2868/martinw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 464 on 2012-07-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Scott](https://answers.ros.org/users/100/scott/) on 2012-07-23**:
Can you do a rostopic list and then paste the output here as well? It might help with the troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had to register the depth points using the dynamic reconfigure *doh*, now rxgraph says it subscribing to the points!

---

Originally posted by [MartinW](https://answers.ros.org/users/2868/martinw/) with karma: 464 on 2012-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0